# Uncaught TypeError: Entities is not a constructor in ('html-entities').XmlEntities;

Tags: node.js, reactjs, html-entities

```js
const Entities = require('html-entities').XmlEntities;
const entities = new Entities();
```

getting Uncaught TypeError: Entities is not a constructor
how to fix this? 
module-> html-entities |  version -> 2.3.3

Comment: Could you solve it ? I'm having same error